# Different behavior in list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x

In my mind this two pieces of code do the same thing:

```
l = [[1,2], [3,4],[3,2], [5,4], [4,4],[5,7]]
```

1)

```
In [4]: [list(g) for k,g in groupby(sorted(l,key=lambda x:x[1]),
    key = lambda x:x[1]) if len(list(g)) == 2]
Out[4]: [[]]
```

2)

```
In [5]: groups = [list(g) for k,g in groupby(sorted(l, 
    key=lambda x:x[1]), key = lambda x:x[1])]

In [6]: [g for g in groups if len(g) == 2]
Out[6]: [[[1, 2], [3, 2]]]
```

But as you see first one gives an empty list while the second one gives what I need. Where am I mistaken?

Comment: Because you can't call `list` twice on the same group; it's an iterator, it gets consumed.

Comment: @jonrsharpe So is there a way to do the same without creating another list?

Comment: Well you could `map` the `list` call over the groups, but why are you trying to jam all of this into one line?

Comment: @UpmostScarab you can simply nest the comprehensions

Comment: @jonrsharpe It's only about not creating another list. Yet i think i could use a generator instead. Why don't you post an answer so I can approve it?

Comment: @Elazar how exactly?

Comment: `[g for g in (comprehension for groups) if len(g) == 2]`. As @jonrsharpe said, it is probably too cumbersome as a single expression.

Comment: @Elazar Yes, you are right. This becomes more complicated.

Comment: Another (complicated) option might be using filter `list(filter(lambda x:len(x)==2, [list(g) for k,g in itertools.groupby(sorted(l,key=lambda x:x[1]), key = lambda x:x[1])]))`

Comment: @Aguy in general, only use `filter` where you actually want an iterator - if you want the list, use a list comprehension rather than passing the iterator to `list` yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `group` is an iterator, you cannot consume it (e.g. by calling `list` on it) twice. For example:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> l = [[1,2], [3,4],[3,2], [5,4], [4,4],[5,7]]
>>> for _, group in groupby(sorted(l, key=itemgetter(1)), key=itemgetter(1)):
...     print('first', list(group))
...     print('second', list(group))
...
first [[1, 2], [3, 2]]
second []
first [[3, 4], [5, 4], [4, 4]]
second []
first [[5, 7]]
second []
```

Instead, you need to call `list` once per group and filter on the results of that, e.g. by using `map`:

```
>>> [lst for lst in map(list, (group for _, group in groupby(sorted(l, key=itemgetter(1))), key=itemgetter(1))) if len(lst) == 2]
[[[1, 2], [3, 2]]]
```

Comment: I'd suggest that for clarity you might ignore the specific iterator here and use a shorter one. Since the question is more general.